# Why isn't Bootstrap-sass working in my ruby on rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bootstrap-sass

I've followed the documentation carefully and reinstalled the bundle and restarted the server numerous times, but it still seems to not work when I test the class "jumbotron". Any help appreciated. I am not an expert by any means.

**Here is my application.scss file**

```
/*
 * This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.css, which will include all the files
 * listed below.
 *
 * Any CSS and SCSS file within this directory, lib/assets/stylesheets, vendor/assets/stylesheets,
 * or any plugin's vendor/assets/stylesheets directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
 *
 * You're free to add application-wide styles to this file and they'll appear at the bottom of the
 * compiled file so the styles you add here take precedence over styles defined in any styles
 * defined in the other CSS/SCSS files in this directory. It is generally better to create a new
 * file per style scope.
 */

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

**Here is my application.js file**

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
// listed below.
//
// Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, vendor/assets/javascripts,
// or any plugin's vendor/assets/javascripts directory can be referenced here using a relative path.
//
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// compiled file.
//
// Read Sprockets README (https://github.com/rails/sprockets#sprockets-directives) for details
// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require_tree .
```

**What I added to my gemfile..**

```
gem 'haml', '~> 4.0', '>= 4.0.7'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.3', '>= 3.3.7'
```

Comment: Do you have the `sass-rails` gem present in your `gemfile`?

Comment: For the question in your title: it can work.

Comment: yes sass-rails gem comes with a new rails app automatically

Comment: Do your other parts of boostrap work?  grid system, button classes, etc?

Comment: rename your `application.scss` to `application.css`, or just create new file like `custom.scss` in `app/assets/stylesheets/` and put all your css there.

Comment: Try this : https://github.com/solitarytraveler/Bootstrap-Build-System